# module map file '/Users/"my_flutter_project_path"/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I'm trying to run my flutter project via xcode on real device.But
getting this error `module map file '/Users/"my_flutter_project_path"/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found`

I browsed for this error and got [this_gitHub_issue_solution](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3816) and followed it but can't get solution.

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727138/firestore-installation-using-cocoapods/59922306#59922306

Comment: have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [CocoaPods 1.9.0](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.9.0-beta/), the capability to specify dynamic/static linkage for each pod in the Podfile should get it better. It introduced the use of `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` which is an even better approach than `use_modular_headers!`.