# Firestore installation using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to install firestore in my project.

When I'm trying to install that, Xcode displays:

> fatal error: module map file '/Users/account/Documents/myapp/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found

or sometimes another errors....

so I've spend so many of times (almost entire 2 days) to solve this problem, but nothing is actually working :/ (deleting derived data and Pods folder, pod deintegrate, pod install and update or cleaning build (Command-shift-k)).

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'myapp' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
#use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
#pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-posd

end
```

this is my `Podfile`. and whenever I delete `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'`, everything's working whereas Firebase/Firestore is not. (surely to recover normal working state, I comment all of pod repositories, (in terminal) type "pod install" and then uncomment top 4 repositories and pod install....)

I really wanna use Firestore, but I can't.

Comment: Try to use an older version of these libraries.

Comment: @ZonilyJame hmm... firestore? or other all of libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore requires latest CocoaPods. As per Google developer

> It should get better with CocoaPods 1.9.0 which is adding the
>   capability to specify dynamic/static linkage for each pod in the
>   Podfile.

Please check this link https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3816

Comment: It seems not working for me. I installed CocoaPods 1.9.0 beta 2. The only difference is I have to add Firebase/Firestore as depedency on my private repo. Maybe it's beaucoup it's in my depedency and not in my podfile ?

Answer (score 4):

We can also force CocoaPods to not apply modular headers for the troubling pods... in this case:

```
pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC', '= 0.0.3', :modular_headers => false
pod 'gRPC-Core', '= 1.21.0', :modular_headers => false
```

Comment: this solution worked for me, with pod version 1.9.0

Comment: Where do I put these lines of text?

Comment: @ScottF on your podfile